# HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error

Tags: jsp

register page .
i am tryiny to store the registar data in database it gives error

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="register.jsp" method="post">
  <center>
   <table>
    <table border="5" width="50%" cellpadding="6" bgcolor="orange" />
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th colspan="5">Registration Page</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>FirstName</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="firstname" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>LastName</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="lastname" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="phone" value="" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""/ ></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </center>
 </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Sucess.jsp

```html
<%@ page import="com.webApp.RegDAo"%>
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.webApp.RegistrarDetail"></jsp:useBean>

<jsp:setProperty property="*" name="obj"/>

<% int i=RegDAo.Submit(obj);

if(i>0)
out.println("YOU ARE SUCESSFULLR REGISTER");
%>
```

its bean classs or pojo class

```html
package com.webApp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.RequestingUserName;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GeneratorType;

@Entity
@Table (name="REGISTRAR_WEBAPP")
public class RegistrarDetail {

 @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name="ID")
 private int id;

 @Column (name="FIRSTNAME")
 private String firstName;

 @Column (name="LASTNAME")
 private String lastName;

 @Column (name="PHONE")
 private String phone;

 @Column (name="PASSWORD")
 private String password;
 public int getId() {
  return id;
 }
 public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
 }
 public String getFirstName() {
  return firstName;
 }
 public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
 }
 public String getLastName() {
  return lastName;
 }
 public void setLastName(String lastName) {
  this.lastName = lastName;
 }
 public String getPhone() {
  return phone;
 }
 public void setPhone(String phone) {
  this.phone = phone;
 }
 public String getPassword() {
  return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
  this.password = password;
 }
 public String toString(){
  
  return "{ ID:"+id+"FIRSTNAME:"+firstName+"LASTNAME"+lastName+"phone"+phone+"password"+password+"}";
     
  
 }
}
```

REGISTERDAoClass

```html
package com.webApp;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class RegDAo {

 public static int Submit(RegistrarDetail r){

  int i=0;

  SessionFactory sf=new Configuration().configure("reg.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

  Session session=sf.openSession();

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(r);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();

 
  return i;


 }

}
```

reg.cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
   "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
  "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
  
  
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory> 
 
 
 <property name="connection.drive_classr">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
 <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate</property>
 <property name="connection.username">root</property>
 <property name="connection.password">vikay</property>
 <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
 
 <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 
 <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
 <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
 
 <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
 
 <mapping class="com.webApp.RegistrarDetail"/>
 
 </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

on console i got this error

```html
Aug 22, 2015 5:11:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/HiberAnnoWebApp] threw exception [org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:51)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
 at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
 at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
 at com.webApp.RegDAo.Submit(RegDAo.java:14)
 at org.apache.jsp.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:76)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

on browser after request it gives this error

```html
HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection

type Exception report

message org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling DriverManager#getConnection
 org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:118)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:140)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:54)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
 com.webApp.RegDAo.Submit(RegDAo.java:14)
 org.apache.jsp.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:76)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Hibernate
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverManagerConnectionCreator.java:51)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
 org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
 org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
 com.webApp.RegDAo.Submit(RegDAo.java:14)
 org.apache.jsp.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:76)
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

i put all the jars in program.

add the my sql connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error it is reg.cfg.xml file now its working fine .but little more proble when is storing the data in database it show first name and last name null  and add the phone and password below

```html
mysql> select *from registrar_webapp;
+----+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
| ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | PASSWORD | PHONE      |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
|  1 | NULL      | NULL     | 123456   | 9741178304 |
+----+-----------+----------+----------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mentioned form action="register.jsp", Have you posted the register.jsp page?

Suggestion: Try to use Servlets for controller's rather than using Scriplets..

If you want, please cross check [here](http://javainfinite.com/jsp-and-servlet/crud-using-jsp-hibernate-jsp-hibernate-example/) for CRUD process using JSP and Hibernate.

Comment: yes  i posted the register page first one is register page